# Python KeyError when using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nlp

I'm following a tutorial on NLP but have encountered a key error error when trying to group my raw data into good and bad reviews. Here is the tutorial link: https://towardsdatascience.com/detecting-bad-customer-reviews-with-nlp-d8b36134dc7e

```
#reviews.csv
I am so angry about the service
Nothing was wrong, all good
The bedroom was dirty
The food was great

#nlp.py
import pandas as pd

#read data
reviews_df = pd.read_csv("reviews.csv")
# append the positive and negative text reviews
reviews_df["review"] = reviews_df["Negative_Review"] + 
reviews_df["Positive_Review"]

reviews_df.columns
```

I'm seeing the following error:

```
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Negative_Review'
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: There is no column called "Negative_Review" in your `DataFrame` - what is the output of `reviews_df.columns`?

Comment: The same error is produced. Do I need to have headings in my csv file before writing this program?

Comment: Yes - having headers is one option. When you do a `read_csv` without any other options - it is going to split at a comma - meaning, everything before the first comma becomes the first column, and so on...It is best to do a `review_df.head()` and `review_df.columns` immediately after `read_csv` and understand what your dataframe looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because you did not understand how to structure your data.

When you do df['reviews']=df['Positive_reviews']+df['Negative_reviews'] you're actually summing the values of Positive reviews to Negative reviews(which does not exist currently) into the 'reviews' column (chich also does not exist).

Your csv is nothing more than a **plaintext file** with one text in each row. Also, since you're working with text, remember to enclose every string in quotation marks("), otherwise your commas will create fakecolumns.

With your approach, it seems that you'll still tag all your reviews manually (usually, if you're working with machine learning, you'll do this outside code and load it to your machine learning file).

In order for your code to work, you want to do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('TestFileFolder/57886076.csv', names=['text'])
## Fill with placeholder values
df['Positive_review']=0
df['Negative_review']=1
df.head()
```

Result:

```
                              text  Positive_review  Negative_review
0  I am so angry about the service                0                1
1      Nothing was wrong, all good                0                1
2            The bedroom was dirty                0                1
3               The food was great                0                1
```

However, I would recommend you to have a single column (is_review_positive) and have it to true or false. You can easily encode it later on.

Comment: Regards. I undetstand a key error is caused when there is no mapping data in the hash table for pandas. However, the added code 'df['review'] = df['review'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('No Negative', '').replace('No Positive', ''))' invokes the same error - this is for when there are no bad or good reviews.

Comment: Do df.head() and see if there is a column named 'review'. Also, did you create the columns 'No Negative'..?  When you do apply lambda, you're iteratively applying a function to all values in a column.

Comment: Upon df.view() there is only the output of the result you posted and thus no column "No Negative. Do i need to create the column first before replacing it. The line is only meant to remove comments without a positive or negative review

Comment: If you want to substitute "No Negative" column, you have to create it first. If you want to drop a line that is neither negative nor positive, that is another entire question and you can find an answer in stack overflow.

Answer (score -1):

```
###This code can run your pandas To a null value is found if null value is find it can break by own ###
import pandas as pd
path = pd.read_excel("C://Users//Public//Documents//python exe files//Excel files//AssetSubLocationMinor.XLSX")
print(path)
column_name = "MinorLocation_Name"  # Replace with the actual column name

for i in range(0,3):
    try:
        value = path.loc[i, column_name]
        # Code to handle the value if it exists
        if pd.isna(value) or value == "":
            print("null value")
        else:
            print("Ok")
    except KeyError:
        print("Column does not exist in the DataFrame")
        break
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).